# Jquery-Tools Tabs - Need a specific tab to load two divs onClick

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tools

I have three tabs using jquery tools tabs. Each tab triggers a different div. However, I need the second and third tab to trigger two divs in separate locations (the main . I have tried using tab index to no avail. So, the question is, how can I get the second and third tab to trigger two divs?

I went back to the basic loading method for tabs.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
});
</script>
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="search-wrapper">
    <div id="navcontainer">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#">Tab 0</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input type="text" name="searchinput" id="searchinput" size="30">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />  

    <!-- I need this div to open onClick of Tab 1 and Tab 2-->
    <div style="display: none" id="categoryselector">
        This will contain specific selectors for the search.
    </div>
</div><!--end of search-wrapper-->


<!-- Below are the main tabs that open correctly -->
<div class="panes">
    <div class="tabcontent">Tab 0</div>
    <div class="tabcontent">Tab 1</div>
    <div class="tabcontent">Tab 2</div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See their docs

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html

Bind to the click event for the tab.

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", {
         onClick: function(event, tabIndex) {
            if (tabIndex == 1 || tabIndex == 2) { 
                $('#categoryselector').show(); 
            }
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: This was the right track. The actual code I ended up using was $(function() {
    $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", {
         onClick: function(event, tabIndex) {
      if (tabIndex == 0) { 
                $('#categoryselector').hide(); 
            }
            if (tabIndex == 1 || tabIndex == 2) { 
                $('#categoryselector').show(); 
            }
         }
    });
});